# Quadratic form involving graph Laplacian

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, block-matrices, graph-laplacian

I have a connected undirected graph of $n$ nodes. Each node $i$ has a vector ${\bf x}_i$ and is connected to $d_i$ neighbours. Let $\tilde{{\bf L}} := {\bf L} \otimes {\bf I}_n$, where $\bf L$ is the graph Laplacian matrix and ${\bf I}_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix. Furthermore, let ${\bf X} = \begin{bmatrix} {\bf x}_1 & \cdots & {\bf x}_n \end{bmatrix}$ be the concatenation of the vectors $\{ {\bf x}_i \}_{i=1}^n$. I want to find a matrix $\bf B$ (related to the graph) such that the term $${\bf X}^\top \left( \tilde{{\bf L}}^\top \tilde{{\bf L}} + {\bf B} \right) {\bf X}$$ can be expressed as a function of only ${\bf x}_i$ and $\sum\limits_{j \in \mathcal{N}_j} {\bf x}_j$, where $\mathcal{N}_j$ is the set of neighbours of node $i$.

Comment: Not sure why you need the $L^T L$. Any matrix $A$ that works for $X^TAX$ can then be written as $B=A-L^T L$.

Comment: @user619894: I didn't quite understand your answer, care to explain further?

Comment: It is not an answer, it is a clarification question: You need to solve for $B$, right? But any solution for $A=L^TL +B$ can be transformed back to $B$ by subtracting, so if I am understanding the question, you are asking for some matrix $A$ that expresses $X^TAX$ as you required. No need to involve $L$ at all?

Comment: @user619894: The original term has only $X^T L^TL X$. As this term cannot be expressed as a function of what I need, I'm looking to add a term that will make this holds true. Hope this helps clarify my question.